# Glossaries style mcolindex change hanging indent

Tags: spacing, glossaries

That's it. How can I change the hanging indent of the glossaries style `mcolindex` from the package `glossary-mcols`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report} %twoside
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Para saber el encoding del archivo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[xindy, nomain, acronym, nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Libr}
{
    name=Librería,
    description={En informática, una librería o biblioteca es un conjunto de recursos y fucniones diseñadas para ser usadas por otros programas. Incluyen plantillas, funciones y clases, subrutinas, código escrito, variables predefinidas...},
    plural=librerías,
}
\newglossaryentry{datos}{
    name=Datos,
    description={Secuencia binaria de unos y ceros que contiene información codificada},
    plural=Datos, 
}
\newacronym{gnu}{GNU}{\textit{GNU's Not Unix} (GNU no es Unix)}
\newglossaryentry{Linux}
{
  name=Linux,
  description={is a generic term referring to the family of Unix-like
               computer operating systems that use the Linux kernel},
  plural=Linuces
}
\newglossaryentry{conmutacion de paquetes}{
    name={Conmutación de paquetes},
    description={Método para enviar datos por una red de computadoras. Se divide el paquete en dos partes, una con información de control que leen los nodos para enviar el paquete a su destino y los datos a enviar},
}
\newacronym{osi}{OSI}{\textit{Open Systems Interconnection} (Interconexión de Sistemas Abiertos)}
\newglossaryentry{gls-ISO}{
name={\textit{International Organization for Standardization}},
description={Organización Internacional de Normalización. Compuesta de varias organizaciones nacionales se encarga de la creación de estándares internacionales desde 1947.},
}
\begin{document}
Hola \gls{Libr} \gls{datos} \gls{Linux}
\glsaddall
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\printglossary[style=mcolindex]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mcolindex` style uses the same formatting as an ordinary index. This starts each entry with `\@idxitem`, which is usually defined by the document class. The standard classes, such as `article`, define this as

```
\par \hangindent 40\p@
```

(40pt hanging indent). You can redefine `\@idxitem` but it needs to be done before the style is set. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent20pt}
\makeatother
```

If your document also has an index, this will also be affected. Another possibility is to redefine the style. For example:

```
\renewglossarystyle{mcolindex}{%
  \setglossarystyle{index}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
     \begin{multicols}{\glsmcols}
     \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \renewcommand\item{\par\hangindent20pt}}%
    {\end{multicols}}%
}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: Renewglossarystyle works well for me, i don't tested the other methods.